# How to grant mount.cifs to normal users and whether unmounting is mandatory before logout

Tags: server, permissions, mount, samba, nfs

OS: Ubuntu MATE 20.04.1 x64_86

I need to create a network drive to a file server (an environment with NFS and Microsoft Active Directory) and be able to read/write into it via a Bash script. After some googling, I found a solution (the following is part of a larger program in my Bash script that mounts the drive):

```
readonly srv_conn_str="//remote-usrs-srv/Users$"
mount.cifs "${srv_conn_str}" ~/drive_usr -o username="${user}",password="${password}",dom="AD",vers=1.0
```

The above code does the job but it works if and only if I run mount.cifs with sudo (root privilege). Now the problem is that this Ubuntu system is actually a virtual machine with GUI, to which multiple users connect. Each of these users need to create the mount point in their `~/drive_usr` directory (using his/her Windows account ID and password). So unless, everyone has the password of the sudo user, I don't see any other way to run this command and obviously that is not an option. Therefore, I have two questions:

**Question 1**:
Is there any system level configuration possible allowing to run mount.cifs as a normal user and not only by the system administrator?

**Question 2**:
Before each user closes the current session, should `~/drive_usr` be unmounted via the **umount** command? Now the reason that I ask this question is obviously that I'm really a beginner in this field, so I don't know whether closing a session without unmounting the already mounted network drives via `mount.cifs` could do any harm to the original data on the remote server, as if we removed a USB stick without unmounting it first which is not recommended and could result in loss of data.

---

**Edit n° 1:** (Based on the solution vanadium suggested )

I appended the following line to /etc/fstab:

```
//remote-usrs-srv/Users$   /home/mylinux_username/drive_usr    cifs user,noauto,rw,suid,exec,dev,iocharset=utf8,username=my_windows_username,domain=AD,vers=2.0                            0            0
```

This almost solved the problem. Now all I need to do **without using sudo** is to run the following in my Bash script:

```
readonly srv_conn_str="//remote-usrs-srv/Users$"
mount.cifs "${srv_conn_str}" ~/drive_usr
```

Which mounts the drive once the user's Windows password has been provided as a command line argument in my script. However, there are still two problems:

1. I can mount without using sudo, yet apparently the **umount command still needs sudo**. What I need is to be able to run mount and umount on ~/drive_usr without sudo privilege.
2. Initially I had added **async** option among provided options in /etc/fstab. Yet this generated the following error:

   **mount error(22): Invalid argument**

And when I run dmesg in order to see what was wrong, this is what I found as error message:

```
CIFS: Unknown mount option "async"
```

So do I understand correctly? CIFS is not compatible with **async**? The reason that I wanted to add async option was that while I was googling to learn more about /etc/fstab, I saw that many suggested that adding this option is rather recommended in order to improve the performance, being really a beginner in this field, I don't know whether this is correct. I'd appreciate for some clarification on this.

Comment: Did you try confguring the mount using fstab? With the option `noauto`, the mount will not be effectuated at startup, and with the option `users`, users will be allowed to mount and unmount anytime.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I modified my post accordingly based on your suggestion. Please view the Edit part.

Comment: `umount` should also work. Are you sure you tried unmounting as the same user who mounted? Eventually try the `users` option: then anyone can mount and anyone (including someone else) can unmount. With respect to `async`: feel free to ask another question. This site has a format where one asks one question at a time.

Comment: I confirm that using 'users' instead of 'user' solved that mount/umount issue for normal users. Many thanks for your time and your help. For other issues I'll ask separate questions as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed what wanadium suggested in comments (many thanks!) which solved the issue for normal users being unable to mount/unmount. Here is the line that had to be added to /etc/fstab

```
//remote-usrs-srv/Users$   /home/mylinux_username/drive_usr    cifs    users,noauto,rw,suid,exec,dev,iocharset=utf8,username=my_windows_username,domain=AD,vers=2.0                            0            0
```